# The difference of Regex between js and java

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have the following Regex to test for mobile numbers: `/^1[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{8}$/`. 
If I have the String `"123456789"`, I test it in Java, and result is false; but in JavaScript, the result is true. Can anyone can tell me the reason?

Comment: I do not believe that the result of that test in Java would be false.

Comment: The regex says, "a '1' followed by EITHER 10 digits or 8 digits.

Comment: @Pointy, wouldn't that be the case if it were `/^1([0-9]{10}|[0-9]{8})$/`, isn't this matching like `/^(1[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{8})$/` ? I didn't try to run this in java btw

Comment: Actually, it says a `1` followed by 10 digits and anything, or a string ending with 8 digits

Comment: @minitech yes you're right. The point is, it matches the search string.

Comment: this is my java code :

Comment: @JCOC611,Because I'm not good at English，thank you for editing my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you’re probably using `match`. Something like that; I’m not really familiar with Java. Anyways, the main idea is that that method only checks for a match at the *beginning* of the string. Your regular expression matches a string starting with `1` and 10 more digits, or a string ending with 8 digits; `123456789` is neither. In JavaScript, all three of `String.prototype.match`, `RegExp.prototype.exec` and `RegExp.prototype.test` check anywhere.

I think you meant:

```
/^(1[0-9]{10}|[0-9]{8})$/
```

But that’s *still* wrong; 123456789 will hardly match that, which is more restrictive. I’m not sure what your intent is, but it just doesn’t work:

- Three missing digits in +12 (345) 678‒9___
- Two missing digits in +1 (234) 567‒89__
- One missing digit in (123) 456‒789
- Two too many digits in 123‒4567 | 89

I don’t know much about other countries’ telephone number formats, though.

Comment: Yes,I need the javaScript's result is false.But it's true.You are right,thank you very much

Comment: @chaser: Then use a group, exactly like the example provided.